# GUI Testing by GWT/smartGWT with Selenium IDE

Tags: gwt, selenium, smartgwt

I'm new here and in Selenium too. I'm trying to test GUI of our smartGWT-Projekt with Selenium. 
I added the user-extension.js,  goto_sel_ide.js and the user-extension-ide.js just like described here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Testing+SmartGWT+with+Selenium?_sscc=t

But my Problem now is that I get Errors when I execute my Records:

*[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/tools.js -> file:///C:/smartgwt-3.0/selenium/user-extensions.js?1352387440820, lineNumber -> 72*

Here is the Line 72: var elem = autWindow.isc.AutoTest.getElement(scLocator);

Yes, I read most of Questions/Answers here about smartGWT/GWT with Selenium.
And in Google I found nothing about this error.

Could someone show me the way?

Must the Project run on local to test with Selenium?

Versions I use for this Test:
Firefox v15.0.1
SeleniumIDE 1.9.1
SmartGWT v3.0 (I'm using local only the user-*.js Files)